# How to parse and manipulate a big chunk of string in the format key=value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fetching some data from an camera's API.

There's a big string returned in the response with this format VCA.Ch0.licenseid=0

Here's a part of the response

```
VCA.Ch0.licenseid=0\r\nVCA.Ch0.enable=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.enablemovobj=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.enablecntline=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.trackmode=surv\r\n
```

Is it possible to parse this string?

Let's say that I want to query about the param VCA.Ch0.enable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ input.split.map { |kv| kv.split('=') }.to_h
#⇒ {
#         "VCA.Ch0.enable" => "yes",
#  "VCA.Ch0.enablecntline" => "yes",
#   "VCA.Ch0.enablemovobj" => "yes",
#      "VCA.Ch0.licenseid" => "0",
#      "VCA.Ch0.trackmode" => "surv"
# }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
string = 'VCA.Ch0.licenseid=0\r\nVCA.Ch0.enable=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.enablemovobj=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.enablecntline=yes\r\nVCA.Ch0.trackmode=surv\r\n'

parsed_result = string.split("\r\n").reduce({}){|result, unit| key, data = unit.split('='); result[key] = data; result }
```

this lets you do...

```
parsed_result['VCA.CH0.enable']
=> 'yes'
```